# Finding convexity intervals of a real valued function without using second derivative

Tags: functions, derivatives

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3951595/485701), someone gave an interesting way to show that the function $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ was strictly increasing without using the first derivative. It got me wondering, is there a way to find the intervals where this function is convex without using the second derivative? I know there is a definition that can be used to prove that a function is convex in a given interval, but I couldn't find a way that could give said interval of convexity.

This came to my mind in hopes of possibly studying convexity prior to second derivatives, so in this case, it could also be relevant wether such methods are less/more complex than the concept of derivatives.

Comment: How does it not use the first derivative?

Comment: At the end of this answer there's a way to prove it algebraically https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3951610/485701

Comment: OK. FYI in the question, you linked to a different answer

Comment: Thank you, I corrected it

Comment: Studying the sign of $f''(x)=\frac{6 x^2-2}{\left(x^2+1\right)^3}$ is pretty straightforward. I don't see the need of looking for alternatives